# Specify length (size) of @Id @GeneratedValue using Hibernate Annotations

Tags: java, hibernate

Is it possible to specify a starting value and the size of an id that is being auto-generated using Hibernate Annotation `@GenerateValue`?  For example, instead of just starting at "1", I would like the field to be 8 characters long and fill in with preceeding 0's (00000001, 00000002, 00000003, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [custom sequence](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/Customsequences) for that, but I would not advise for it. You don't need to store the primary keys as strings (and you would have to, if you want leading zeros).

What you should do is - append the zeros whenever you have to display the ID to the users, otherwise store it in the database as a number.